# No me funciona la función each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy probando en jQuery la función para cambiar varios elementos en bloque (each), pero no encuentro el error, no me cambia la clase de los td.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cuadrícula en Bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="miElemento">

</div>
<form action="miPagina.php" id="miFormulario" target="">
<input type="text" id="miCampo" value="Texto del campo"></input>
</form>
<a class="miEnlace" href="#" title="">Enlace</a>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="miTabla">
   <tr>
  <td class="">Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#miTabla td").each(function(element){
    element.addClass("miNuevoEstilo");
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación de jQuery, [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) puede recibir dos parámetros: el primero es el index del elemento en el orden de la iteración (un entero) y el segundo es el elemento sobre el cual se itera en ese momento.

Se puede hacer de dos formas:

1. Sin pasarle ningún parámetro y utilizando `this` para referirse al elemento actual:

   ```
   $("#miTabla td").each(function(){
     $(this).addClass("miNuevoEstilo");
   });
   ```
2. Pasar los dos parámetros y utilizar el segundo parámetro, algo similar a lo que intentaste:

   ```
   $("#miTabla td").each(function(index, element){
     element.addClass("miNuevoEstilo");
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`$.each` no funciona igual que le `forEach` de JavaScript. Para acceder al elemento dentro del `each` puedes hacer `$(this)`:

```
$("#miTabla td").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("miNuevoEstilo");
});
```

Al final el código quedaría así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cuadrícula en Bootstrap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="miElemento">

</div>
<form action="miPagina.php" id="miFormulario" target="">
<input type="text" id="miCampo" value="Texto del campo"></input>
</form>
<a class="miEnlace" href="#" title="">Enlace</a>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="miTabla">
   <tr>
  <td class="">Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#miTabla td").each(function(){
    $(this).addClass("miNuevoEstilo");
});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta no es una respuesta directa, pero cabe destacar que `addClass` **aplica el estilo a todos los elementos** que retorne la query. Por lo tanto no seria necesario usar each ya que lo hace internamente.

Fíjate este ejemplo:

```js
$("#miTabla td").addClass("miNuevoEstilo");
```

```css
.miNuevoEstilo {
  color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="miTabla">
   <tr>
  <td class="">Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Hola</td>
  <td>Hola</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Como aporte dejo otra solución sin utilizar jQuery que bajo mi punto de vista es mucho más elegante (y de paso nos ahorramos la carga de los 94KB de la versión para producción de jQuery).

```
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('#miTabla td')
[].forEach.call(tds, td => {
  td.addClass('tuNuevoEstilo') 
})
```

Y una versión más al estilo ES6 utilizando [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) podría ser algo así:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('#miTabla td')].forEach(td => {
  td.addClass('tuNuevoEstilo') 
})
```